# How to access session in __construct?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.3.4 I can't access session variables in construct. Is there any way do to this? Here is my code:

```
    // app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
    class Controller extends BaseController {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

        public function __construct() {
            $t = Translation::where('language_id', Session::get('language_id') )->get();
            View::share('t', $t);
        }
    }
```

P.S. I need to load translations from database, before every page load, for all controllers and views.

Comment: create a middleware for that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.

In your controller file

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $t = Translation::where('language_id',Session::get('language_id')->get();
            View::share('t', $t);Session::get('language_id');

           return $next($request);
     });
}
```

Comment: thanks. Now I got the session value in middleware function! But $this->languageId is null outside the middleware function. Why? Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind - I find out that passing variables from middleware to controller is another big problem for my app. Can't make it work in any ways I can find on stackoverflow. So answer for now is ok, because the next problem is another issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Also you can write like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if(Session::get('user_id') == NULL)
        {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }
    });
}
```