# Custom api authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make authentication based on API in laravel. Here is my process flow. First of all, I get data from API. If it is valid then I keep true value in the session. Through middleware, I check every route if it is authenticated or not. Am I on right track?

```
Session::put('authenticated', true);
session::get('authenticated');
```

Should I add anything to make it more efficient? Here the problem is I can not handle **/login** route. After successful login, it can be the visit the login page. Also I can't get session value in **LoginController function __construct()**  . Thanks in advance. I am using laravel 5.5

Comment: I can't answer to the rest of it, but session variables and Auth cannot be accessed directly in the controller __construct functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267376/how-to-access-session-in-construct and https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: I handled according that . It shows **Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object**

Comment: Ideally, it would be unwise to use session storage to track the rest API calls. If that is what you are doing.  You should try using JWT tokens or simply an access token stored in your DB to check the authenticity of the API calls coming in. Pass the token as an Authorization header and verify them in your server logic.